# @RequestBody and @Valid not validating empty/blank string field in kotlin object

Tags: spring, validation, kotlin, controller, request

My request is parsed into the Kotlin object that is the request body in the controller. Currently, if the fields are null - a validation exception is thrown which is exactly what i want.

However, I am using @NotBlank and this doesn't seem to validate the way it's meant to against "" or " ". What am I missing?

@NotEmpty also doesn't check against "". They both seem to just check against null, which is only part of what I'm looking for.

Essentially I am looking for the request not to be null, the list field not to be null, the inner BumblebeeEvent in the list not to be null, and each Event to have it's fields validated (e.g. not null, "" or " ").

Here is my controller:

```
@Controller
class BumblebeeEventController {

    @PostMapping("/publish")
    fun eventIntake(@RequestBody @Valid payload: BumblebeeEventList) : ResponseEntity<String>{
        return ResponseEntity("Published ${eventList.size} event(s) successfully",HttpStatus.OK)
    }

}

class Event(@NotBlank val localTime: String){}

class BumblebeeEvent(@NotNull val event: Event)

class BumblebeeEventList(@NotNull val events: List<BumblebeeEvent>){}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
class Event(@NotBlank val localTime: String){}

class BumblebeeEvent(@NotNull @Valid val event: Event)

class BumblebeeEventList(@NotNull @Valid val events: List<BumblebeeEvent>){}
```

You must indicate that the validation must go also in the nested object